# I just downloaded Java SE 8 off of the oracle website but I cannot find the actual application

Tags: java, download, installation, dmg

The dmg file downloaded fine from Oracle and then I opened it and it installed the JDK although it seemed to have skipped the area to choose my document installing location. Now I cannot find where the actual program is. I have tried downloading it again and repeating the process but I still am unaware of where the JDK was installed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check in C:\Program Files\Java . This is the default location .

Comment: Windows 64 bit - `C:\Program Files\Java`

Comment: Windows 32 bit - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a command line (assuming it was added to your path), type **java -verbose**. It will show verbose JAR loading as the JRE starts up (note, this technically IS an error as you haven't supplied a class to run, but it'll get what you need). The lines in the output should show the location of the installation (again, pending it was added and in your path).